# tail -f on a named pipe behaves strange

Tags: linux, named-pipes, tail

I am trying to use named pipes for interprocess communication but I'm seeing strange things I cannot understand. 
I have this "writer" code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define FIFO_NAME "american_maid"

int main(void)
{
    char s[300];
    int num, fd;

    mknod(FIFO_NAME, S_IFIFO | 0666, 0);

    printf("waiting for readers...\n");
    fd = open(FIFO_NAME, O_WRONLY);
        printf ("FD = %d", fd);
                    printf("got a reader--type some stuff\n");
    while (gets(s), !feof(stdin)) {
        if ((num = write(fd, s, strlen(s))) == -1)
            perror("write");
        else
            printf("speak: wrote %d bytes\n", num);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Now when I do a "tail -f american_maid" the tail blocks waiting for a writer.
Then I run the writer code and it finds that tail -f is waiting on the other end of the pipe. So far so good. 
When I type anything in the writer application, nothing shows up in tail window, HOWEVER, as soon as I close (Ctrl-C) the writer app, ALL that I had typed appear in the tail window.

It's like the writer has to close before tail could show anything. Any ideas what is happening and why it's happening and how I can fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try using `cat`? Did you try running `strace tail -f filename`?

Comment: Keep typing.  Type more than 4,096 (`PIPE_BUF`, usually) characters.  Now does something show up?

Comment: Other advice: Don't use named pipes for interprocess communication. Or if you do make it one way only. UNIX local sockets are much better for two-way communication. I know from experience and from trying to create a system that wouldn't get lost in the weeds if another message got sent to the pipe accidentally.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong here. `tail` wants to extract the *last* lines. To determine which these are, it is looking for end-of-file in the fifo, which it only sees after the writer has closed the writing end of the fifo.

Comment: This would be correct for `tail` in its normal mode, but `tail -f` is different.

Comment: @Zack: can you please provide evidence for that?

Comment: `strace` it and see for yourself.

Comment: @Zack: OK, I tested by passing data directly to `tail` using a pipe, where the `-f` switch is ignored. Nonetheless, I don't see how that renders my answer wrong, since `tail` still looks for the last lines of input.

Comment: You should have observed `tail -f`, fed from a pipe, beginning to produce output upon the first short read or `EAGAIN`, *not* only after it got a zero-byte read (aka EOF).  But it is possible that not all `tail` implementations are the same in this regard.

Comment: @Zack: Interesting. Note that POSIX requires the `-f` switch to be ignored when there is no file argument to `tail` and stdin is a pipe/fifo. And if I understand you correctly, you get different output for `echo one; echo two` and `echo one; sleep 1; echo two` when feeding to `tail -f -n 1`? That looks just broken.